# Java HashMap class throws a NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap, bluej

I am using BlueJ and testing the HashMap class to see how it works. Below is the code I used to test the class. There is an error that is thrown in line 23, during the first attempt to call the `fillMyMap()` method in the constructor.

I tried deleting the call to `fillMyMap()` in the constructor. The HashMapTester object is instantiated, but the same `NullPointerException` is thrown when I call that method explicitly.

I tried rewriting the `myMap` variable declaration, but using a different syntax results in a failure to compile.

I've tested other `HashMap` code (e.g., from Objects First with BlueJ), and that code runs fine, so there is not a Library, class, or package problem.

I tried changing the variables, thinking I accidentally hit a reserved word. The same result. What is wrong with this code?

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class HashMapTester
{
    //Fields
    public HashMap<String, String> myMap;

    // The constructor is supposed to construct a new
    // HashMap object with variable name myMap.
    // The fillMyMap() method call simply fills the HashMap
    // with data prior to testing it.
    public HashMapTester()
    {
        HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        fillMyMap();
    }

    // fillMyMap() methods is supposed to fill up 
    // the keys and values of the HashMap<String, String> 
    // object.
    public void fillMyMap()
    {
        myMap.put("doe", "A deer...a female deer."); //<-- ERROR OCCURS HERE!
        myMap.put("ray", "A drop of golden sun.");
        myMap.put("me", "A name I call myself.");
        myMap.put("fah", "A long, long way to run.");
        myMap.put("sew", "A needle sewing thread.");
        myMap.put("la", "A note to follow sew.");
        myMap.put("tea", "It goes with jam and bread.");
    }

    public String sing(String note)
    {
        String song = myMap.get(note);    
        return song;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Is declaring a local variable in the constructor, not instantiating the field variable.

Use

```
this.myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly now.

Comment: I was also able to get it to work by deleting the `this` keyword as well.

Comment: Yes, the this is not necessary in this case. It would only be necessary to disambiguate names. For example, imagine that the constructor also had a parameter named `myMap`. `this.myMap` would refer to the class field and simply `myMap` would refer to the parameter. Since in your example there is only one variable named `myMap`, this is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a local variable in your constructor. You're not initializing the instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've written `HashMap<String,String> myMap=new HashMap<String,String>();` (stress on the first bit). You are declaring a new local variable here.

The `HashMapTester()` function should be:

```
public HashMapTester(){
  this.myMap=new HashMap<String,String>();
  fillMyMap();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest, Simplest Fix. Erase this: `HashMap<String, String>`

```js
import java.util.HashMap;

public class HashMapTester {
    public HashMap<String, String> myMap;

    public HashMapTester(){
        myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();   //<-- I WAS THE ERROR
        fillMyMap();
    }

    public void fillMyMap() {
        myMap.put("doe", "A deer...a female deer."); //<--NO ERROR OCCURS HERE!
        myMap.put("ray", "A drop of golden sun.");
        myMap.put("me", "A name I call myself.");
        myMap.put("fah", "A long, long way to run.");
        myMap.put("sew", "A needle sewing thread.");
        myMap.put("la", "A note to follow sew.");
        myMap.put("tea", "It goes with jam and bread.");
    }

    public String sing(String note){
        String song = myMap.get(note);    
        return song;
    }
}
```

Comment: I love the fact that you showed the new error location! Very clever.

Comment: Yea man, you know it, I try hard to help others. I was even about to write an essay about Null Pointer Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

in your constructor u are using

```
HashMap<String,String> myMap=new HashMap<String,String>();
```

when you should be using

```
this.myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

this is how you instantiating the field variable and not just declaring a new local variable map.